# How do I import Microsoft Edge favorites from a Windows 10 backup

Tags: microsoft-edge

I reinstalled Windows 10 and do not have the favorites in the browser.  I have a  backup of win 10.  How do I import the favorites from the backup.

Comment: You can test this following step. BACKUP before doing anything. Try to copy the folder from `C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Packages\some-folder-named-with-edge`.

Comment: Harold, How did you make your Backup?

Comment: I made a backup using the win 7 program in Windows 10.  It has backed up the C drive.

Comment: You are SoL.  Per https://techjourney.net/change-microsoft-edge-favorites-storage-location-disable-enable-ese-database/ : "Beginning from Windows 10 Build 10565 ... the Favorites in Microsoft Edge storage location are now in an ESE database file instead of the a Favorites folder." ... "The changes make it impossible to manage, change, add, delete, import, export, backup, restore, save or delete favorites by using just Windows Explorer or File Explorer, as now all favorites are stored in encrypted database, instead of individual .lnk link."

Answer (score -1):

If you still have the backup, you may be able to restore the entire folder where the Edge database is stored.  However, this will only work if the current version of Windows 10 is the EXACT same version as when the backup was made.

If so, then just navigate in the backup and restore the entire contents of this folder:  C:\Users\WHAT_YOUR_NAME_IS\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe

However, if the version has changed, then you'll need to use a 3rd-party application to read the old database and produce an HTML export file that you would subsequently use on the current version of Windows with an HTML import operation.

http://www.edgemanage.emmet-gray.com/Articles/RecoverLostFavorites.html

PS: I am the author...

Comment: Please disclose when your are linking to your own website or are suggesting your own applications